# How to prevent Eclipse from automatically open debug panel when it hits a breakpoint in debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have an annoying problem, If I minimize the debug panel while debugging, it still is showed everytime when application hits a breakpoint.

Is it possible to tell eclipse not to show this panel automatically when breakpoint is being hit?

Comment: Ermm ... how else is Eclipse supposed to tell you that it has hit the breakpoint???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Window->Preferences->Run/Debug` and you will find a checkbox `Activate the debug view when a breakpoint is hit`. So, turn it off

Answer (score 1):

Everything is under:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug
```